# Resizable window with ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a wpf c# application.
In my window I want to start with a certain height when it opens. But I also want to allow the user to be able to resize the window.
My window has a dockpanel with lastChildFill set to true. It has on the left a tree to pick a section you would like to see it's details, in the middle a seperator and on the right the section's details (you need last child fill so that this will get all the space left).
The code looks like this:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="#344755">
        <TextBlock Text="Header" Background="#344755" Foreground="White"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5">
        <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeV">
                <telerik:RadTreeView.Items>
                    <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="General" />
                    <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="General2" />
                    <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="General3" />
                    <telerik:RadTreeViewItem Header="General4" />
                </telerik:RadTreeView.Items>
            </telerik:RadTreeView>
        <Separator/>
        <Grid >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                  <ItemsControl>

                         <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"  Margin="5">
                            <Grid  >
                                <TextBlock Text="Something"></TextBlock>
                                <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                           </Grid>
                        </DockPanel>
                        // And many more dock panels
                   </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid >
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This is my problem: If I don't give the second dock panel height than the window automatically grows bigger and the scroll never shows. If I do give height, then the scroll does show but if the user resizes the window the dock panel doesn't resize and so doesn't the seperator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update me if my answer helps.

Comment: Your lay out is massively overcomplicated, your clearly new to wpf because your missusing the ItemsControls

Answer (score 0):

You need to Rethink your layout
for one thing you don't need to have a dock panel to fill the available area

here is a quick description of the most common layouts

- StackPanel Creates a List of items in a top down or left to right
  arrangement
- Grid Attaches item to a grid define by sized rows and columns (uniform grid does the same but with rows and colums set to equally fill the available space)
- Dockpanel attaches items to its edges using the order they are added
  and the Dock property, with by default the last item set to fill the
  middle
- Canvas position items at fixed distances from the edges

So given controls w,x,y,z if you want w to be on the left z on the right and x & Y to share the centre

```
<DockPanel>
    <w DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <z DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <x/>
        <y/>
    </UniformGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

if you wanted w to cover the first 1/4 of the screen and x,y & z to be stacked vertically on the remaining 3/4 and scrollable you would do

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
        <ColumnDefintion \>
        <ColumnDefintion Width="3*" \>
    <Grid.ColumnDefintions>
    <w/>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <x/>
            <x/>
            <x/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

if you only have 1 item inside a layout container then that container is not required

A quick fiddle with you above code and it simplfies to

```
<DockPanel Background="#344755">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Header" Foreground="White"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeV">
        <TreeViewItem Header="General" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General2" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General3" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General4" />
    </TreeView>
    <Separator/>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

or if you really don't have a collection to bind the items control to

```
<DockPanel Background="#344755">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Header" Foreground="White"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeV">
        <TreeViewItem Header="General" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General2" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General3" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="General4" />
    </TreeView>
    <Separator/>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right">Something</CheckBox>
            ... 
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```